# Choosing row by max number of characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem i'm working on that i will greatly simplify:

```
x=data.frame(times = c(100,200),code = c("AB,CD,X","X"))
```

How can choose the row with the highest number of characters in the code column?

i was using nchar but not coming up with the correct answer.  Thx

Comment: Please show your attempt with `nchar`.

Comment: `data.frame` by itself will generate `factor`s for your `$code` column, but `'nchar()' requires a character vector`. Perhaps `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` would work better?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to remove punctuation etc. from the character strings

```
max(nchar(as.character(x$code)))
```

Should work